# Syntax for transforming column in a dataset

Tags: dataset

Suppose I have a dataset `a`, featuring a column labeled `n`, whose values are all string representations of integer values.  I want to generate a new dataset `b` identical to `a` in everyway, except that its `n` column contains the actual integers represented by the strings in `a`'s `n` column.

The following strategy does not work, but at least it may convey what I'd like to do:

```
b = a;
b[[All, "n"]] = Dataset[<|"n" -> ToExpression[#]|> & /@ (Normal@a[[All, "n"]])];
```

(The second assignment above produces the error `Set::partd: Part specification b[[All,n]] is longer than depth of object.`)

Importantly, I want to do this in a way that is agnostic to the position of column `n` among the columns of `a`.  (After all, the whole point of using named columns is to allow for such column-order-agnostic code.)

After a ***lot*** of trial-and-error I hit upon this:

```
b = Association[#, "n" -> ToExpression[#n]] & /@ a
```

...which strikes me as a very convoluted and counterintuitive way to perform a very natural operation.  Is there clearer syntax for this sort of thing?

Comment: Does `a[All, "n" -> FromDigits]` work?

Comment: @CarlWoll: Thanks, but no, I get the error `OptionValue: Unknown option n for Query`.

Comment: Then you should provide a MWE of the sort of dataset you are interested in. I think the relevant documentation example is [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset#847234791)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrived data. The 2nd column is populated with string representations of the numbers in the 1st column.

```
SeedRandom[42];
With[{n = 5},
 a = 
   Dataset[<|"i" -> #, "n" -> ToString[#]|> & /@ RandomSample[Range[101, 199], n]]]
```

[image: dataset]

Dataset with 2nd column converted from strings to numbers.

```
b = a[All, {"n" -> ToExpression}]
```

Verification

```
a[All, "n"] // Normal // InputForm
```

> `{"155", "167", "105", "116", "107"}`

```
b[All, "n"] // Normal // InputForm
```

> `{155, 167, 105, 116, 107}`